# get a custom query result containing Clob in Java Spring App

Tags: java, spring, clob

I need to get a very long string from Oracle DB in Spring App, but using a function returning clob leads to internal server error 500. How to get a custom query result containing Clob?

PL/SQL function returning a very long string in clob:

```sql
create or replace function getVeryLongString(id_ in number)
    return clob as

    CURSOR cur IS select x.TARGET || ' pX=' || x.px as tpx -- to get concat string in order of PX desc
                  from (
                           select distinct a.ID,
                                           a.TARGET,
                                           MAX(a.PX) OVER (PARTITION BY a.TARGET, a.ID) as px
                           from BA_ACTIVITYDATA A
                           where A.TARGET is not null
                             and a.ID = id_
                           order by px desc
                       ) x;
    l_data clob := '';
begin
    FOR fld IN cur
        LOOP
           l_data := l_data || fld.tpx || ' | ';
    end loop;
    return rtrim( l_data, ' | ');
end
;
```

I use this function in Query in Java Spring app:

```java
public interface TargetRepository extends JpaRepository<List, Long> {
    @Query(
            value = "select t1.fieldA,\n" +
                    "       t1.fieldB,\n" +
                    "       t2.fieldC,\n" +
                    "       getVeryLongString(t3.value1) as fieldD\n" +
                    "from tableA t1\n" +
                    "join tableB t2 on t1.id = t2.id\n" +
                    "join tableC t3 on t3.id = t2.id\n" +
                    "where t.id = :id",
            nativeQuery = true
    )
    DataTypePX getDataById(Long id);
}
```

TargetActivity interface looks like:

```java
public interface DataTypePX {
    String getFIELDA();
    String getFIELDB();
    String getFIELDC();
    String getFIELDD();
}
```

Using the above code leads to 500 ERROR.

to fix it I need to change function getVeryLongString as returning varchar2 - it works, but it leads to cutting of result string only to 4000 symbols:

```sql
create or replace function getVeryLongString(id_ in number)
    return varchar2 as

    CURSOR cur IS select x.TARGET || ' pX=' || x.px as tpx -- to get concat string in order of PX desc
                  from (
                           select distinct a.ID,
                                           a.TARGET,
                                           MAX(a.PX) OVER (PARTITION BY a.TARGET, a.ID) as px
                           from BA_ACTIVITYDATA A
                           where A.TARGET is not null
                             and a.ID = id_
                           order by px desc
                       ) x;
--     l_data varchar2(32767) := '';
    l_data clob := '';
begin
    FOR fld IN cur
        LOOP
           l_data := l_data || fld.tpx || ' | ';
    end loop;
    return rtrim( substr(l_data, 1, 4000), ' | ');
end;
```

Comment: Please add the error. For CLOB handling you need to do some additional work when using plain JDBC over JPA. Hence direct String access of the Clob will not work (which is probably the reason for the 500).

Comment: there is no error in java terminal, as response get just: HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Comment: That error doesnt happen without a reason, so there must be a stacktrce somewhere (yes not in your browser but should be in your console where your app is running).

Comment: I mean console of IntelliJ IDEA where my app is running - there is no error in this case

Comment: That is weird, you must have disabled something then. When running enable debug mode, this will give lots and lots of output!, but gives you more information.